# Laravel with PHP-FPM is better or laravel octane?

Tags: php, laravel, fpm, laravel-octane

Consider your application having other factors common excluding laravel + php-FPM and Laravel Octane like apache server, ram size, processors speed etc.

So can somebody tell me why and which is better with performance wise?

I found lot of content about laravel octane and php-fpm but I didn't find any comparision between them, Either both have complete different purposes and I am miss understanding its meaning or I am digging correctly.

Answer (score 7):

PHP-FPM is not specifically related to Laravel while Octane is. There are plenty of sites that give you some metrics on using PHP-FPM that don't need to be rehashed here.

Laravel Octane is a laravel-specific project for improving the performance of your Laravel application and isn't really an apples to apples comparison with PHP-FPM.

The real question is, if you're developing Laravel today is PHP-FPM the best way to serve the application.

Given the old age of the PHP-FPM project it is preferred to optimize and host your Laravel project using Octane. It is (arguably) the real future of Laravel and decouples the serving of your project from a server like Apache or nginx and instead lets Laravel serve itself via Swoole and can be coupled with high-performance serving engines like RoadRunner.

If you're interested in performance, Laravel Octane is the optimal choice, but you will have to factor in the new concepts of semi-stateful programming for your application.

This is something of an opinion-based topic so SO might not be the best place to get answers, but hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is benchmark of Laravel over Octane and Nginx + PHP FPM

Laravel Octane and Nginx + PHP-FPM

**Laravel over Nginx + PHP-FPM**

[image]

**Laravel + Octane**

[image]

You can read this in details at : https://blog.keytech.dev/what-is-laravel-octane-how-to-use-it-with-laravel

Comment: Hi, thank you for the really great benchmark. I would like to know what tools did you use for benchmarking an endpoint?